# post_logout_redirect_uri is empty OpenIdConnect IdentityServer

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4, openid-connect

I'm trying to redirect my users to the app landing page after logging out but I can´t find a way to set post_logout_redirect_uri parameter.
I'm using OpenIdConnect and IdentityServer so after initiating a signOut from the client, the user gets redirected to IdentityServer end-session endPoint but post_logout_redirect_uri is empty.

Client:

```
var props = new AuthenticationProperties()
{
  RedirectUri = HttpContext.Request.Scheme + "://" + HttpContext.Request.Host.Value
};
await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(props);
await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, props);
```

As I understand, method HttpContext.SignOutAsync() with "oidc" then redirects to IdentityServer end-session endpoint:

[image]

As you can see, post_logout_redirect_uri query params is empty. This is happening automatically because of configuration, so I would expect I could set the post_logout_redirect_uri somewhere, but I couldn´t find it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The post_logout_redirect_uri can be set on startup where you register your external auth scheme with `AddOpenIdConnect`. The `OpenIdConnectOptions` which you set up have a property called `SignedOutCallbackPath`:

```
/// <summary>
/// The request path within the application's base path where the user agent will be returned after sign out from the identity provider.
/// See post_logout_redirect_uri from http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-session-1_0.html#RedirectionAfterLogout.
/// </summary>
public PathString SignedOutCallbackPath { get; set; }
```

You might also check:

```
/// <summary>
/// The uri where the user agent will be redirected to after application is signed out from the identity provider.
/// The redirect will happen after the SignedOutCallbackPath is invoked.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>This URI can be out of the application's domain. By default it points to the root.</remarks>
public string SignedOutRedirectUri { get; set; } = "/";
```